# VS Code Graphical Interface doesn't open, gpu process is exited due to errors during initialization

Tags: 20.04

After trying to open the output of pstree -p in vs code, graphical interface of vs code started to not work. When i run the command "code -s", i am getting the following output:

```
[13818:0901/122407.741437:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[13854:0901/122407.876107:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[13875:0901/122407.965904:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[13875:0901/122407.972852:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
Version:          Code 1.70.2 (e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662, 2022-08-16T05:36:25.715Z)
OS Version:       Linux x64 5.15.0-46-generic
CPUs:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6254 CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 x 3092)
Memory (System):  15.63GB (8.96GB free)
Load (avg):       3, 3, 3
VM:               100%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     --crash-reporter-id 2326a521-bef3-4269-8b91-b060f5e44ee9
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                              unavailable_software
                  canvas_oop_rasterization:               disabled_off
                  direct_rendering_display_compositor:    disabled_off_ok
                  gpu_compositing:                        disabled_software
                  multiple_raster_threads:                enabled_on
                  opengl:                                 disabled_off
                  rasterization:                          disabled_software
                  raw_draw:                               disabled_off_ok
                  skia_renderer:                          enabled_on
                  video_decode:                           disabled_software
                  video_encode:                           disabled_software
                  vulkan:                                 disabled_off
                  webgl:                                  unavailable_software
                  webgl2:                                 unavailable_software

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    0      160   11966  code main
    0       32   11969     zygote
    0       80   12067       gpu-process
    0       32   11970     zygote
    0        0   11972       zygote
    0       48   12008     utility-network-service
    0      176   12036     window (● pyenv.cfg - Visual Studio Code)
    0       80   12080     extensionHost
    0      128   12088     shared-process
    0       64   12113       ptyHost
    0       64   12157       fileWatcher
```

restarting the system and pkill code does not help. Apt purge code and installing did not help either. Other programs such as firefox are running without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by first "ALT+F2" and typing "r" into the opened dialog window.